# How to apply NLP when text contains a lot of numbers, product dimension

Tags: python, nlp

I am working to find nearly duplicates between short text fields. As an example, a text field looks like this:

`TUBING,SHRINK: 3/8",4' LG,FLEXIBLE POLYOLEFIN,HEAT,2:1`

in my case, these special characters and numbers are meaningful and removing them might impact to find the right duplicates. Any suggestion on how to deal with this kind of information for the case of text similarity. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need these numbers and special characters, you can just filter out them:

```
import string

a = 'TUBING,SHRINK: 3/8",4\' LG,FLEXIBLE POLYOLEFIN,HEAT,2:1'

# Keep letters, ',' and ' ' characters
''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.ascii_letters + ' ,', a))
```

Output:

`TUBING,SHRINK , LG,FLEXIBLE POLYOLEFIN,HEAT,`

And search for duplicates between filtered strings.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But in my case, might be that these numbers make the difference between what is a duplicate and what is not. So, removing them I think is not a good idea. But also replacing for example " -> feet or ' - > inches and keeping in my model, might happen that since these are very common words through the dataset might add insignificant similarity between texts.